# Speeding up the rails 3 development server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

Now that Rails 3 is out, my favorite dev-mode plugin (rails-dev-boost) is broken. I'm working on a large application (>100 models and controllers) and loading them all every request takes more than ten seconds. I could turn config.cache_classes on, but then I might as well run in production mode since I have to restart the server every change.

Is there something out there that could speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That plugin owner (rails-dev-boost) is working on getting it running with rails3, so hopefully soon!

I sure wish rails did that kind of stat-optimization out of the box!

https://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost

Here's the link to the rail3 branch (might disappear if/when the updates are moved into the core release)
https://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost/tree/rails3

Comment: Awesome, this made life so much happier.